# Google Apps Script - Add different menu item based on user settings in Properties service?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I'm working on a Form addon that needs 2 things:

- On the first time that user opens the addon, he will see "Get Started" menu item, after that he will configure some settings in order to use the addon
- After that, on the second time that he opens the addon menu, he will see other menu items such as "Feature 1", "Feature 2", ... and he won't see the "Get Started" menu item anymore because he has already configured the settings

I thought that it would related to the `onOpen` function. Here is what I tried:

```
const onOpen = () => {
  try {
    const userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
    let isFinishedSetup = userProperties.getProperty('IS_FINISHED_SETUP')

    if (isFinishedSetup === '1') {
      FormApp.getUi()
        .createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Feature One', 'featureOne')
        .addItem('Feature Two', 'featureTwo')
        .addToUi()
    } else {
      FormApp.getUi()
        .createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Get Started', 'showGetStarted')
        .addToUi()
    }
  } catch (err) {
    FormApp.getUi()
      .createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Get Started', 'showGetStarted')
      .addToUi()
  }
}
```

Basically, I try to get the IS_FINISHED_SETUP property from the PropertiesService, check if it's true.

In case it can not getUserProperties(), I handle it in the `catch` statement

But **this won't work**, the addon menu button doesn't show up.

---

In the console, I see the error `you don't have the permission to call getUserProperties` or something like that.

I searched Google and I found the reason is: the onOpen function can't use services that require scopes

But you can only authorize it after the menu is shown

So how can I handle this situation? I want different menus based on if user finished setup or not.

Comment: You need to set up a installed onOpen trigger on clicking `showGetStarted`  shown to user on simple onOpen

Comment: @TheMaster: Thank you, your comment is always valuable. I remember that you helped me with another issue before :D But can you please give a little more specific detail on that? A step by step description on how to do what you said is great

Comment: @TheMaster: I checked the document here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers =>  However, the installable version can call services that require authorization. **The installable version runs with the authorization of the user who created the trigger**, even if another user with edit access opens the spreadsheet. So it means that getUserProperties will return my properties even if someone else open the form?

Comment: `So it means that getUserProperties will return my properties even if someone else open the form?` Ahh yes. Sorry, I don't think this is feasible through installable triggers. [This](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#the_complete_lifecycle) might help. See whether onOpen() runs in NONE or LIMITED, then see whether you can access userProperties too(Document properties will be accessible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in this link https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#the_complete_lifecycle

Thanks to @TheMaster

```
const onOpen = (e) => {
  const menu = FormApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()

  if (e && e.authMode === ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // Add Get Started menu item (works in all authorization modes).
    menu.addItem('Get Started', 'showGetStarted')
  } else {
    // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
    const documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()

    const isFinishedSetup = documentProperties.getProperty('isFinishedSetup')

    if (isFinishedSetup === '1') {
      menu.addItem('Feature One', 'featureOne')
      menu.addItem('Feature Two', 'featureTwo')
    } else {
      menu.addItem('Get Started', 'showGetStarted')
    }
  }

  menu.addToUi()
}
```

---

**A note here when you try to test this by using "Test as add-on"**:

You must manually choose the `AuthMode` when testing as add-on.

If you choose `AuthMode.NONE`, it will **NOT** show anything other than `Get Started` menu item.

You need to choose `AuthMode.LIMITED`

[image]

Comment: Were you able to access `userProperties`? Also, what did you do to enable arrow functions?

Comment: @TheMaster: Yes, I was able to access userProperties. About your second question, please check this repository https://github.com/labnol/apps-script-starter OR https://github.com/enuchi/React-Google-Apps-Script. They added support for ES6, which makes developer's life easier